# Laravel Imap connect() slow | reuse?

Tags: php, laravel, email, server, imap

I am using [laravel-imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap) to connect to my email server and get all mailboxes and messages.

I noticed that the connect() method is slow, it takes 4-5 sec.:

```
$start = microtime(true);

$oClient = new Client([
    'host'          => env('MAIL_HOST_IN'),
    'port'          => env('MAIL_PORT_IN'),
    'encryption'    => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION_IN'),
    'validate_cert' => true,
    'username'      => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password'      => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'protocol'      => 'imap'
]);

// Connect to the IMAP Server
$oClient->connect(); 

\Log::info('Connect: ' . strval(microtime(true) - $start));
```

Thats it, there is no additional code. I also use `getFolders()` and loop through them to get messages.
I count/get unseen messages and do more operations, but they are all fast.

I am asking this, because if I login into my mailbox through the website, the performance is much better 1-2 sec. And the operation is the same, I get the mailboxes and a count on unseen messages. **So why it is slow via script?**

In case it simply is like that and I cant change it, what are some possible solutions? The only idea I have right now it to reuse the connection in multple functions, so at least I connect only once.

Comment: Maybe, it is related to the query you send.
Probably you get all folders and all messages.
But the client you use gets only the latest 10 or 20 on the first page.

Comment: In the example I do not get any of these. I suspect that it simply is slow via script. Maybe because I am not on the server. Thats the only difference, if I login in the browser, then I am also on the same server as the mailbox. Now I am testing from localhost. The communication localhost -> server makes the difference. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Are ordinary TCP and HTTP requests from you local environment comparable in performance to browser-based requests? I.e. is the increased latency, unique to IMAP connect?

Comment: Try using a networking tool like `openssl s_client` or `socat`and attempt the login yourself to see if the IMAP server itself is taking a long time to connect and/or authenticate.

Comment: Your firewall is probably broken and discards full-length packets, ICMP, or something like that. You can analyse exactly what's happening using wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @all. I will try all of that on monday and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @everyone who commented.

I can confirm now that there is no issue with the code/package.

It seems that something on my local machine was responsible for the slow connect time.
I dont know exactly what it was, maybe a broken firewall.

I uploaded the code to my server. The performance was much better, it connected immediately.